# Xbindkeys bind mouse button to emulate Super Key

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

how can I bind my mouse button 9 to emulate `Superkey (Left) + Right key`?

I tried it with the following, but it does't work.

```sh
xvkbd -xsendevent -text '\[Super_L]\[Right]'
```